# How to downgrade Python 3.7 to 3.6 on RPI4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, downgrade

I am trying to downgrade my python version from 3.7 to 3.6 on raspberry pi4.
is need to uninstall 3.7 first and reinstall python3.6?

does anyone know of a way to solve this?

Comment: you don't have to unistall old version - you can have many different versions at the same time and run `python3.7` or `python3.6` and `pip3.7` or `pip3.6`. If system uses old version for some functions then uninstalling old version you may crash system. And most Linux use Python for some functions.

Comment: main question: why do you need 3.6 ? What is wrong with 3.7 ?

Comment: @furas beacuse i have a sensor(vl53l0x), dependant with smbus lib, but smbus seems doesn't support python3.7, so i need to downgrade python to 3.6 (i am sure it work on python 3.6)

Comment: I found [smbus2](https://pypi.org/project/smbus2/) which probably works with Python 3.7 . And you really need 3.6 then don't downgrade but install 3.6 together with 3.7 - they keep modules in different folders, and they use different programs `python3.7` , `python3.6` and `pip3.7`, `pip3.6`

Comment: @furas  it's work, thanks a lot!!